# How to Set minimum and maximum date dynamically in Element-ui date picker

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am having 2 date pickers for startDate and endDate.
In startDate Picker,I want to disabled all dates before endDate and vise versa.
how to disable dates using elemnt-ui.

                  >

Comment: What have you tried? Posting your code along with the question tends to help.

Comment: ` <el-date-picker
                  v-model="toDate"
                  type="date"             
                  >`
 ` <el-date-picker
                  v-model="fromDate"
                  type="date"                    
                  >`

these are my 2 date pickers.
I have added  :picker-options= disabledDate function
but above code is desabling my whole calendar

Answer (score 16):

This is an old question but I asked myself the same today. You can achieve this using the `disabledDate` picker option. Here's an example on how to disable all future dates:

```
<el-date-picker
  :picker-options="datePickerOptions"
</el-date-picker>
```

Then in your data object:

```
data () {
  return {
    datePickerOptions: {
      disabledDate (date) {
        return date > new Date()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

fist of all you should define picker options for your end date input.
The main problem is using **this** keyword inside the disabledDate method of picker options, so you should move exactly method outside the **data** definition to the **methods** part
So, complete code should looks something like this:

```
data () {
    return {
        task: {
            start_at: new Date(),
            end_at: new Date()
        }
        dueDatePickerOptions: {
            disabledDate: this.disabledDueDate
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    disabledDueDate (time) {
        return time.getTime() < this.task.start_at
    },
    validateEndDate () {
        if (this.task.start_at > this.task.due_at) {
            this.task.due_at = this.task.start_at
        }
    }
}
```

And **HTML** part of this example should looks like:

```
<el-date-picker @input="validateEndDate" v-model="task.start_at" type="date"></el-date-picker>
<el-date-picker v-model="task.end_at" :picker-options="dueDatePickerOptions" type="date"></el-date-picker>
```

**Notice:**
validateEndDate method will be triggered after changing startDate and check if endDate before startDate then fix endDate to be equals.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, since `this` is not defined inside the scope of `picker-options` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get between, you can try it:

```
datePickerOptions: {
  disabledDate: this.disabledDueDate
}
```

and your method:

```
methods: {
  disabledDueDate(date) {  // format Date!
    return !(date >= this.start && date <= this.end)
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting the picker options inside the computed property, and using the `moment.js` library to check if the date is in between two dates:

```
computed: {
  inBetweenDatesPickerOptions() {
    return {
      disabledDate: (time) => {
        return !moment(time.getTime()).isBetween(this.form.start_date, this.form.end_date);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in the markup you can set the options by using the `:picker-options` prop:

```
<el-date-picker 
  v-model="form.in_between_date" 
  :picker-options="inBetweenDatesPickerOptions" 
  type="date">
</el-date-picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Composition Api**

```
 <template>
 <el-date-picker
  v-model="selectedDate"
  :disabled-date="disabledDate"
  type="daterange"
  placeholder="Select date">
 </el-date-picker>
 </template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const selectedDate = ref(new Date());
    const minDate = ref(new Date());
    const maxDate = ref(new Date());

    const dateStart =  new Date(1677794400 * 1000);
    const dateStart =  new Date(1678399200 * 1000);
    minDate.value.setDate(dateStart.getDate()-1)
    minDate.value.setMonth(dateStart.getMonth())
    minDate.value.setFullYear(dateStart.getFullYear())
    
    maxDate.value.setDate(dateEnd.getDate())
    maxDate.value.setMonth(dateEnd.getMonth())
    maxDate.value.setFullYear(dateEnd.getFullYear())

   function disabledDate(vDate){
        return vDate < minDate.value || vDate > maxDate.value;
    }


    return {
      selectedDate,
      disabledDate
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

An easier solution would be limiting min/max values dynamically. I suggest this:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="dateFrom" :max="dateTo">
<input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="dateTo" :min="dateFrom">
```

This would limit the date picker to proper date ranges.

Comment: The answer doesn't have any relation to the implemention of date limitation in datepicker from Element UI